# Access Database already exclusively opened by another user

Tags: ms-access, iis-7.5

I have an access database that sits on server x iis is running on server y.  One of my web pages access data from the access database.  If someone has the access database open say a end user on our network the web pages fail with a ...already opened exclusively by another user error message.

I created a local access database and used linked tables in order to access the tables that way.  Even still I get the already opened exclusively by another user error.  If I go through windows explorer and browse out to server x and open the database I can without issue.  So my question is how can I simulate the same type of connectivity to the database without the error being thrown is it a matter of permissions to the access database or something within my connectionstring that would allow me to access the database.

Since it throws the error during my connection.open command I am figuring it is either permission related or something additional I need to add to my connection string.  I have granted full control for the IIS AppPool\ on the local directory in which my local instance of the access database resides in but didn't seem to make a difference.

My connection string looks like:

```
Private Shared connSheriff As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\serverx\directory\Access\MyDatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=property;")
```

Comment: Are you opening the database as an administrator? If you suspect the connection string then it's probably worth posting it.

Comment: Private Shared connSheriff As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\\serverx\directory\Access\MyDatabase.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=property;")

Comment: You might consider tagging your question with the web programming language you're using in order to reach a wider audience. Also, I recommend you put some line breaks, punctuation, and maybe other formatting in your question to make it more readable.

Comment: Have you also granted full control for the IIS AppPool in the folder where the .mdw file is located?

Comment: I think this is a permissions problem.  I'm currently trying to resolve a similar problem myself.  I was able to get the app working with a local database by giving full permissions on the db folder to the local ASPNET user.  If you check the Application event logs under your Computer Management console, you may get more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are some [options within the mdb](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/set-options-for-a-shared-access-database-mdb-HP005188297.aspx) that change how the database is opened by default, these should be your first port of call particularly setting the "default open mode" to "shared".

You've already split the database (data tables in the shared back-end, linked tables and the rest in the front-end). Make sure that each user uses a separate copy of the front-end mdb, otherwise you'll get locking issues on this.

There is a command line switch (/excl) that sets exclusive mode, but you just omit this to open the db shared so I doubt this is a problem.

You probably already know this but the "[Shared](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx#methodscope_topic7)" modifier has nothing to do with sharing between applications or users, but shares the connection variable between instances of your class (the c# equivalent is "static")