# Access to Access Database is Denied when connecting from one pc to another in Network

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, permissions

I have a network with a server and many computers connected to it. I have a software installed on the server which is accessed and used by many clients.

Now i have created a reporting tool using `c#/Winforms`. In summary it connects to Access DB and creates reports. And each pc on the network contains an Access DB , so we give path to that DB and it creates report for that pc we connect using path like:

\WinPc\Tmuser\Database\users.mdb

When `WinPc` is the computer name , `Tmuser` is the shared folder on the pc which contains the database. This works perfectly fine when i have the application (c#/Winform) on the man server it can connect to any pc and generate reports.

But when i put the tool on any pc and give path of Db on another pc it gives error as below:

[image]

And i cannot figure out why this error shows up , as when i check the path in explorer it opens the access Db just fine. Kindly let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: According to the error message it says that the database is already opened exclusively by another user ?   Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229622/access-database-already-exclusively-opened-by-another-user

Comment: @Tommo1977 but why it works perfectly fine when on the server .The issue is only when its on one of the pc on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the permissions, the pc it was connecting too needed credentials when from another pc, instead of server so it did not let it open files... Changing the current user to `domain account` worked

Answer (score 0):

as the error says, the database is exclusively open by another user.

what i would suggest, because you have a lot of PCs that may try to access the DB is to make  a server-client project so every client send requests to write a line to the main server, and the server side in the main server will take those requests and write them to the DB, that way only one computer will write to DB and no one will lock the DB

also, i may not seeing your code, but i'm guessing you forgot to release the DB at some point. always use `Using` statement when using streams or Connections

Comment: its not that case, if i just use the app on server to connect to same db it will connect fine. The db is not locked its just wont let me open it when on another pc.

Comment: @confusedMind if it is indeed the case then you have a permissions problem, and a server client program as i suggested will work and will might be better then let the other PCs permissions on a DB on the main server...

Comment: suppose the other pc needs credentials to login , when using explorer too so can the error above be in case of that?

Comment: @confusedMind u can try using it and let us know how it worked out for you... but without permissions, i think you'll have some more problems. that all depend on the implementation

Comment: @ The issue was the permissions, the pc it was connecting too needed credentials when from another pc, instead of server so it did not let it open files...

Changing the current user to domain account  worked .

Comment: Thank you would not have done it if you did not mention permissions :).

Comment: @confusedMind any time mate